# Can we study the effects of Quantum reflection on heavy atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, solid-state-physics, reflection, graphene

From what I've looked at, it feels like QR has only been studied on light atoms like He, Ne, Na, H, etc. But can we study this effect on heavy atoms like Rb-87.

If not, is it because of the reflectivity is minimal. Or do heavy atoms start to behave classically?

Comment: What do you mean by 'quantum reflection' of an atom?

Comment: What I mean is why can't we study the reflectivity of heavy atoms, say on a graphene film. All the papers I looked at used light atoms. 

Hope that clears it up

Comment: There have been many articles written on ion reflection off of surfaces. A pretty core part of understanding sputtering. Basically all the noble gases. You might have to look back to the 1960's and 70's to find much of it.

Comment: @AdDave How about giving us a link to one of those papers? What are they studying? Electronic or vibrational excitations of the surface, maybe also their dispersion?